# How to pair BLE without BT Classic(BR) between Android and Windows 10

Tags: android, bluetooth, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

Between Android P and Windows 10 1903, I tried to pair them. Android P Phone is a Client(BLE Master) and Windows 10 laptop is a server(BLE Slave) broadcasting itself.

In Android P default bluetooth setting menu panel, it automatically scans and shows the scanned BT/BLE list. The Laptop default BT Classic advertiser and my BLE Advertiser are discovered by the scanner. I wanted only BLE pairing and I only clicked BLE Advertising in the list in order to pair. After confirming the passkey in both the phone and laptop, it suddenly showed BT Classic and BLE both.

It seems that those BT Classic(BR) and BLE are always paired and unpaired together with the basic pairing method.

So, my question is 
**How to pair BLE without BT Classic(BR) between Android and Windows 10?**

---

In Android,
I tried createBond(), finding whether there is a secure mode that I can change but I failed.

In Windows,
I used C# Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts nuget package so that I can use BLE APIs.
So I used Windows.Devices.Bluetooth package.
I tried to find whether I can change BLE GAP(General Access Protocol) but it seemed to be unaccessable.